# Determine winner of a TicTacToe game

Tags: c#, tic-tac-toe

i'm trying to find the winner of a 3x3 TicTacToe game. I user input N which is number of moves, and then N moves like (1,0), (0,2), etc. (X strats the game). At the end of the game the program should return who wins the game (X or 0) or "draw" if there is no winner. I have the following code:

```
namespace ConsoleApp20;
public class Program
{
    public static string Tictactoe(int[][] moves)
    {
        int[] row = new int[3];
        int[] col = new int[3];
        int diag1 = 0;
        int diag2 = 0;
        const int c1 = 2;
        const int c2 = 3;
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            int x = moves[i][0];
            int y = moves[i][1];
            var inc = i % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1;
            row[x] += inc;
            col[y] += inc;
            if (x == y)
            {
                diag1 += inc;
            }

            if (x + y == c1)
            {
                diag2 += inc;
            }

            if (Math.Abs(row[x]) == c2 || Math.Abs(col[y]) == c2 || Math.Abs(diag1) == c2 || Math.Abs(diag2) == c2)
            {
                return i % c1 == 0 ? "X" : "0";
            }
        }

        return moves.Length == 9 ? "Draw" : "Pending";
    }
}
```

I need a suggestion about how to reduce the cyclomatic complexity of this method from 11 to 10.

Comment: Why all the downvotes and no comments?

Comment: @QuasiStellar - I upvoted your comment before reading the code. After reading, I can't revoke the upvote lol. In looking at the code, it doesn't look like it's coded to play like tic tac toe and doesn't function as described in the question description.

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview! Can you please share with a sample moves array?

Comment: [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having a proper context, here are my suggestions.
*Where I had made any assumptions I stated them before any suggestions.*

### Constants

#### Assumption(s)

- `c2` represents the dimension of the TicTacToe's matrix

#### Suggestion(s)

- You should define them on the class-level rather than inside the method
- You should use better naming than `c1` and `c2` to express your intents
- You should use `c2` in the arrays declarations as well `new int[c2];` to ease the future work if you need to support 2x2 or 4x4 TicTacToe as well

### User input

#### Suggestion(s)

- User can provide any data textual data via the console interface
- Please make sure that input is in the right format (use `int.TryParse`)
- and between the right range

```
if (n < lowerLimiter || n > upperLimit) 
   throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(...);
```

- Depending on the requirements you might need to implement a retry logic which runs until the user provides a valid input

### Jagged array

#### Assumption(s)

- The first dimension represents the move ordinal
- The second dimension represents the coordinates (x and y in your case)

#### Suggestion(s)

- It seems like that the second dimension of the jagged array will always contain 2 elements

  - It might make sense to use a dedicated structure for that
  - Either by using some built-in ones like [`Point` struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.point?view=net-6.0) or creating your own
- Iterating through a jagged array can be done by a `foreach`

  - I'm uncertain how does `N` relates to the first dimension of the `moves`, so this might not be applicable for your use case

```
foreach (var (move, moveIndex) in moves.Select((array, index) => (array, index)))
{
    var (x, y) = (move[0], move[1]);
    var inc = moveIndex % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1;
    ...
}
```

### Ternary conditional operator

#### Suggestion(s)

- Rather than having guard expression to do an assignment only if certain criteria is met you can use `?:` operator here as well to stream-line your code

```
diag1 = x == y ? diag1 + inc : diag1;
diag2 = x + y == c1 ? diag2 + inc : diag2;
```

- Please spend some time to try to find better names than `diag1` and `diag2`

### Single return

#### Suggestion(s)

- Try to aim for having only a single `return`

  - Rather than calling a `return` inside the `for`/`foreach` loop use `break`

```
int? lastMoveIndex =  null;
foreach (...)
{
    ...
    if (Math.Abs(row[x]) == c2
        || Math.Abs(col[y]) == c2
        || Math.Abs(diag1) == c2
        || Math.Abs(diag2) == c2)
    {
        lastMoveIndex = moveIndex;
        break;
    }
}

return lastMoveIndex.HasValue
        ? lastMoveIndex.Value % c1 == 0 ? "X" : "0"
        : moves.Length == 9 ? "Draw" : "Pending";
```

Comment: For example, if I have to user input like: N=5 and then (1 0) (1 1) (0 2) (2 2) (2 0) each on new line. Those brackets representing moves for X (first) and 0 (second). How can I add them on a matrix if this would be inputed as string arrays separated by " "?

Comment: @DragosBogdan Could you please help me understand what does this `(1 0) (1 1) (0 2) (2 2) (2 0)` sequence mean?

Comment: These are the positions where X and 0 are placed in a 3x3 matrix, first number is the row, second number is the column.

Comment: @DragosBogdan How do you determine which pair of numbers are representing an `X` or an `0`?

Comment: First pair is X, second pair is 0 and so on. So odd index is X and even index is 0.

Comment: @DragosBogdan So, just to clarify my understand. X is placed on 2nd row 1st column cell. 0 is placed on 2nd row 2 column cell. etc. Is my understanding correct? If so, what exactly is your question? In code review we review working code, so if your code is still under development and have some questions about the implementation itself then StackOverflow might be a better place for that.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74329540/verifying-the-winner-of-a-tic-tac-toe-game?noredirect=1#comment131223681_74329540